# 404 Error in Node Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Not Found

404

```
Error: Not Found
    at c:\Users\wf\WebstormProjects\nodeExpress\app.js:33:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\wf\WebstormProjects\nodeExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (c:\Users\wf\WebstormProjects\nodeExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at c:\Users\wf\WebstormProjects\nodeExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (c:\Users\wf\WebstormProjects\nodeExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (c:\Users\wf\WebstormProjects\nodeExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at c:\Users\wf\WebstormProjects\nodeExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:618:15
    at next (c:\Users\wf\WebstormProjects\nodeExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (c:\Users\wf\WebstormProjects\nodeExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
    at router (c:\Users\wf\WebstormProjects\nodeExpress\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
```

[image]

router code:
//about.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("/about route");
    res.render('about', { title:'About',name:'Praveen' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

//app.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var about = require('./routes/about');
//var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/about', about);

//app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;

enter code here
```

I'm getting above error if I try to access different route in my node application. Please help

Comment: What do you mean 'diferent'? A route that you didn't configure?

Comment: Where's your routes code? What route are you trying to access?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that the route in the about file is actually being resolved as `/about/about`. If you try open that URL it should work fine.

This is because in `app.js`, you say 'forward all requests that start with /about to about.js', so in about.js all routes already start with `/about`: `app.use('/about', about);`

To fix this, simply update the route in `about.js` to:

`router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {`